# Rename pandas column values from unstacked pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have pandas pivot table `merge2` that looks like:

```
   Site   TripDate       Volume    Early_Vol  Percent_Vol
0  024l 2004-12-02  1117.134948  1117.134948     0.000000
1  024l 2005-05-07   390.980708  1117.134948    -0.650015
2  024l 2006-10-07   321.110175  1117.134948    -0.712559
3  024l 2007-10-13   527.631767  1117.134948    -0.527692
4  024l 2008-02-02   597.165065  1117.134948    -0.465449
```

I then subset `merge2` into `sub1`

```
sub1 = merge2[['Site','TripDate','Percent_Vol']]
sub1= sub1.set_index(['Site','TripDate'])
```

`sub1` looks like:

```
             Percent_Vol
Site TripDate               
024l 2004-12-02     0.000000
     2005-05-07    -0.650015
     2006-10-07    -0.712559
     2007-10-13    -0.527692
     2008-02-02    -0.465449
```

I then unstack `sub1` into `t` to look like:

```
           Percent_Vol                                                
Site              024l      029l      033l 035l_r    035l_s    041r_r   
TripDate                                                                
2004-06-01         NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN   
2004-11-13         NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN   
2004-12-02    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000    0.0  0.000000  0.000000   
2005-05-07   -0.650015 -0.290539 -0.300276   -1.0 -0.075511 -0.298801   
2006-10-07   -0.712559 -0.769020 -0.393304   -1.0 -0.520052 -0.284686
```

It seems like I have two levels for my columns names in `t` (i.e. `Percent_Vol` and `Site`) and I only what `Site`.  Is there a way to change the column names to just `Site`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
t.columns = t.columns.droplevel()
```

Comment: I knew it was easy!  Thanks